# Make the radio button icon to center

Tags: android, radio-button

I have 3 RadioButton like below [image]

The . text is getting the centre, not the icon. I need both the icon and text to center

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Test2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Test3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"        
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Test1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Test2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Test3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: But when the linear layout is added all the radio button getting selected. Radio group property not working.